# Inno Setup Exit Setup page shows buttons in system language, not in setup language

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

When canceling a Inno Setup installation via the [Cancel] button, the "Exit Setup" page gets opened. On this page the main text is shown in the language that was selected when started the setup procedure. But the buttons for chose yes/no they are showing the language what is the current windows system language.
Is there a way to fix this?
Expected is, that also the buttons are shown in the selected setup language...
(The setup is compiled with Inno Setup 6.1.2)

[image]

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks :-)